# Terminate activity diagram from subactivity

Tags: c, uml, diagram, termination, activity-diagram

I´m trying to draw an UML activity diagram for a fnction that is (highly simplified) represented by the following code snippet. My intention is to have a subactivity for the lines that check the mode parameter (if-else).

```
ErrorType DoSomething(int mode) {

    if(mode==MODE1) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        return MODE_NOT_AVAILABLE;
    }

    SomethingElse...

    return NO_ERROR;
 }
```

You can see, the return-Statement in the else-Block leads to termination of function *DoSomething*. So if it´s executed, there is no way for *SomethingElse...* to be executed.

As I mentioned, this else-block should be in a subactivity. 
How do I visualize that an action in a subactivity (*return MODE_NOT_AVAILABLE*) has the consequence that it´s parental activity diagram has to be in a final state?

In the following picture you can see my try to solve it. Is this a correct solution?

[image: UML activity diagram]

Comment: this question seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792687/loop-in-uml-activity-diagram-using-a-region

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with some kind of exception, I'd model it with an exception handler like you see here http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/images/screenshots/uml2_tutorial/ad11.GIF. Even though your concrete implementation uses if/else, that should be a way which makes it easy to understand what you want to achieve (prevent the subroutine from being executed in wrong mode).

You can see more details about the notation here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30169

It depends on how much you want to dictate the actual implementation. UML itself is langage-unaware, and so are most stakeholders.

Comment: @BMD correct Google search terms for this feature in UML activity diagrams are ```interruptible region``` and ```interrupting edge```. For another more details see "interrupting edge" in [Kirill Fakhroutdinov, UML Activity Diagrams Reference](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html) and "exception handling" in [Conrad Bock, UML 2 Activity and Action Models Part 6: Structured Activities](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_05/column4/)